# pd.to_datetime returning NaT when date is valid

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I am trying to convert a string to a datetime type in Python using Pandas, I scraped the data from a webpage. A sample of the data is given below. When I convert this using the pd.to_datetime function I receive NaT values but I'm not sure why, the object type is changed to datetime successfully however.

I have two values which should be "2021" but are "20201". I have replaced these and then converted to date time:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace("20201", "2021", inplace=True)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

I have also tried the below:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = "%d/%m/%Y", errors = "coerce")
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

If I do not replace these values and instead just convert to datetime directly, ignoring the "20201" is out of range error, the code works fine and does not produce NaT values.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors = "ignore")
```

| Date | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/01/20201 | a | b | 2 |
| 08/01/20201 | b | c | 2 |
| 09/01/2022 | c | d | 1 |
| 10/01/2022 | d | e | 1 |
| 13/01/2022 | e | f | 3 |
| 14/01/2022 | f | g | 3 |
| 17/01/2022 | g | h | 3 |

Updated Dict:

```
  {'Unnamed: 0': {351: 351, 352: 352},
 'Date': {351: '17/4/20201', 352: '17/4/20201'},
 'Selection': {351: 'Pour La Victoire', 352: 'Wiley Post'},
 'Stake': {351: 1.0, 352: 1.0},
 'Odds Advised': {351: 6.5, 352: 2.5},
 'Profit / Loss': {351: -1.0, 352: -1.0},
 'Bet Type': {351: 'Win', 352: 'Win'}}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce with the `df` you posted. Can you share `df.head(5).to_dict()`?

Comment: Instead of format, you can also pass `day_first=True` to `to_datetime`.

Comment: This is the raw df from the dict `{'Unnamed: 0': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4},
 'Date': {0: '07/01/2022',
  1: '08/01/2022',
  2: '08/01/2022',
  3: '08/01/2022',
  4: '09/01/2022'},
 'Selection': {0: 'Chookie Dunedin',
  1: 'Come On Girl',
  2: 'Faraway Thoughts',
  3: 'Chance',
  4: 'Tulane'},
 'Stake': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0},
 'Odds Advised': {0: 3.0, 1: 1.83, 2: 0.91, 3: 2.75, 4: 22.0},
 'Profit / Loss': {0: -1.0, 1: -1.0, 2: -1.0, 3: 2.75, 4: -1.0},
 'Bet Type': {0: 'Win', 1: 'Win', 2: 'Win', 3: 'Win', 4: 'Win'}}`

Comment: @BeigeSponge I can't reproduce. `pd.to_datetime` works perfectly with this dictionary you provided.

Comment: @rafaelc more troubleshooting in the question. It seems to be a issue with a different line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem might be that you use `inplace=True` and `Series.replace` replaces the whole string, you can use `Series.str.replace`

```
df['Date'].replace("20201", "2021", inplace=True)
# or
df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace("20201", "2021")

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

```
print(df)

        Date    A    B    C
0 2021-07-01    a    b  2.0
1 2021-08-01    b    c  2.0
2 2022-09-01    c    d  1.0
3 2022-10-01    d    e  1.0
4 2022-01-13    e    f  3.0
5 2022-01-14    f    g  3.0
6 2022-01-17    g    h  3.0
```

Comment: This solves it but do you know why this returns all values as NaT, not just the two that have been changed?

Comment: @BeigeSponge `inplace=True` won't return anything.